# Why do i need to cast here?

Tags: java, android-studio

This does not calculate properly in floats.

```
System.out.println(tileWidth);
System.out.println(Gdx.graphics.getWidth());
float drawPPU = 200 / Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
float drawWidth = drawPPU * tileWidth;
float drawHeight = drawPPU * tileHeight;
System.out.println(drawPPU);
System.out.println(drawWidth);
```

Gives this output:

```
125
360
0.0
0.0
```

But when i cast my `INTS` like `FLOATS` this it does calculate properly:

```
float drawPPU = 200 / (float)Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
float drawWidth = drawPPU * (float)tileWidth;
float drawHeight = drawPPU * (float)tileHeight;
```

I am pretty sure I never did these basic calculations like this and it took my a while until i found what was actually wrong with my viewport. I mean:

```
 (float = 200 / 360) == (float = 200.0 / 360.0)
```

So is there something wrong with my setup/compiling or am i mixing things up in some way?

Comment: if everything on the right hand side is an integer, then it remains an integer until it gets assigned to a float. You need to coerce at least one of the values on the right hand side to a float to get floating point math.

Comment: The link to the duplicate has a title nobody with this problem will ever find. Not that mine is any better ;)

Comment: @MennoGouw: It's a general problem description but there isn't anything better when you don't know what the underlying problem is. Googling "*java float division*" yields several several posts on the subject.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel True, funny thing is i have been programming for a while now with java but never ran into this. Or i did without figuring out the actual bug :).